# Pushing my local postgres database to heroku error

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql, pg

I have a brief question that's been puzzling me for a little while. Background I am attempting to migrate my local postgres to Heroku. I am using powershell CLI and using the following statement

`heroku pg:push [MYDATABASE] DATABASE_URL --app [MY HEROKU APP]`. When I submit next request if for a password which I understand is my postgres database password. Complication is my postgres USERNAME is postgres, but the CLI doesn't request a username first. I am unsure how to parse my username with the heroku statement above.

I have tried `PGUSER=xxxxxx PGPASSWORD=yyyyyyy` ahead of my heroku statement and I get an error

Please can you help ?

`PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=password heroku pg:push [MYDATABASE] DATABASE_URL --app [MY HEROKU APP]`

```
PGUSER=postgres : The term 'PGUSER=postgres' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

Comment: Did you find a solution currently having the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

same problem for me before.
Pls run `SET PGUSER=postgres`first.

Then run `heroku pg:push [MYDATABASE] DATABASE_URL --app [MY HEROKU APP]`
It will promot you to input your password afterwards.

Comment: Doesnt work for me